# Точное совпадение двух слов в строке в любом порядке с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Собственно, вопрос в заголовке темы. 
Пытаюсь сделать что-то типа поиска по хэш тэгам.
Представим, что есть строки

```
1. [#массив #циклы]
2. [#циклы #массив]
3. [#циклы #массив #остальное]
```

Мне хочется сделать два типа поиска:

1. Поиск по точному совпадению тэгов в любом порядке.
   Допустим мне нужно найти строки, в которых встречаются тэги `#массив` и `#циклы` и ничего больше. Тогда результатом поиска должны быть строки 1 и 2
2. Поиск по наличию двух тэгов `#массив` и `#циклы` в строке с возможностью наличия в строке и других тэгов. Тогда результатом будут все три строки.

В обоих случаях количество тэгов, по которым осуществляется поиск, может быть любым.
Возможно ли сделать это с помощью регулярки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть все теги из перечисленных, могут быть и другие:

```
^(?=.*#массив\b)(?=.*#циклы\b)
```

Нет никаких других тегов кроме перечисленных:

```
^(\s*#(массив|циклы)\b\s*)+$
```

Есть только перечисленные теги и каждый встречается не менее одного раза:

```
^(?=.*#массив\b)(?=.*#циклы\b)(\s*#(массив|циклы)\b\s*)+$
```

Есть только перечисленные теги и каждый встречается ровно один раз:

```
^(?=.*#массив\b)(?=.*#циклы\b)(\s*#(массив|циклы)\b\s*){2}$
```

PS: Предполагается что в тегах нет дефисов, если есть, надо заменить `\b` на `\b(?!-)`.

Comment: Ух... представляю регулярку-монстра, когда автор захочет 10-ок тегов искать ;)

Comment: Да вроде даже ничего сложного в ней не будет - никакой магии - тупо копипаст.

Comment: Это да, но размеры...

Comment: Первая работает, вторая почему-то не находит строки 1 и 2

Comment: @AlexanderTukanov, квадратные скобки убери - нужно совпадение целой строки.

Comment: отлично! спасибо

Comment: а можно сделать, чтобы квадратные скобки тоже учитывались в регулярке? Они нужны мне для визуального отделения хэш тэгов от остального текста? Я сейчас разными вариантами пробовал их вставить в регулярку, но не получается

Comment: `\[` после `^` и `\]` перед `$`, остальное не трогать.

Comment: да, разобрался. Спасибо за ответ

Comment: @AlexanderTukanov, если проблема решена, прими ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 0):

В любом случае, так как критерии поиска заранее неизвестны, то регулярку вам придется строить на ходу, что бы добавить туда поисковые значения => уже предполагается какой-то язык программирования.

Раз предполагается наличие ЯП, то, на мой взгляд, проще разбить строку на теги такой регуляркой `#[^\s]+` и в итоге вы должны получить массив значений. Дальше, просто, выполняете перебор и все.

Comment: да, вы правы, над этим я уже думал. Тогда на данный момент меня интересует в принципе, возможно ли в конкретно этом случае сделать регулярку с проверкой на два тэга

Comment: @AlexanderTukanov ну сверху ответили на ваш частный случай.